# codes are not dismissing keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, dismiss

I added resignFirstResponder and touchesBegan to my code but the keyboard is not dismissing. I already checked the delegate and assigned delegate to textfields but still no sign of dismissing.

Please help spot the error? (i'm guessing it might be about multiple textFields?)

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class SignUpViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBAction func BackToFirstPageButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        performSegueWithIdentifier("BackToLogInPage", sender: self)
    }

    func SignOutForEmailVerification() {

        PFUser.logOut()
        performSegueWithIdentifier("BackToLogInPage", sender: self)
    }

    @IBOutlet var UsernameTextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet var PasswordTextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet var EmailTextField: UITextField!

    var ActivityIndicator:UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()

    @IBAction func SignUpButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        if UsernameTextField.text == "" || PasswordTextField.text == "" || EmailTextField.text == "" {

            let SignUpAlert = UIAlertController (title: "Error in form", message: "Please fill in the blanks", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

            SignUpAlert.addAction((UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in

            })))

            self.presentViewController(SignUpAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        } else {

            ActivityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50))
            ActivityIndicator.center = self.view.center
            ActivityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
            ActivityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
            view.addSubview(ActivityIndicator)
            ActivityIndicator.startAnimating()
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()

            var user = PFUser()
            user.username = UsernameTextField.text
            user.password = PasswordTextField.text
            user.email = EmailTextField.text

            user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success, error) -> Void in

                self.ActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()

                if error == nil {

                    let EmailVerificationAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Email Verification", message: "Please click the link in an email we have just sent you", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

                    EmailVerificationAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: .Default, handler: { EmailVerificationAlert in self.SignOutForEmailVerification()})
                )

                    self.presentViewController(EmailVerificationAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }

        })
        }

    func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        self.UsernameTextField.delegate = self
        self.PasswordTextField.delegate = self
        self.EmailTextField.delegate = self

    }

    func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

        func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

            self.view.endEditing(true)

        }

        func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {

            textField.resignFirstResponder()

            return true

        }    
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**When user taps "Return" key on the keyboard**

As you already added the `UITextFieldDelegate`, try modifying this code :

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {
    self.UsernameTextField.resignFirstResponder();
    self.EmailTextField.resignFirstResponder();
    self.PasswordTextField.resignFirstResponder();

    return true;
}
```

This will work when the user taps the button return on the keyboard.

Your mistake is as you said handling multiple text fields. Also you have to say which one you want to resignFirstResponder().

**When user taps screen**

User could also dismiss the keyboard by tapping anywhere on the screen.
Here we have a `UITapGestureRecognizer` that detects the tap to dismiss keyboard. It is an alternative solution.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissKeyboard")
view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

func dismissKeyboard() {

    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. i tried this but still no sign of dismissing... any other possible solutions? or any chances its about the setting of the stimulator?

Comment: Have you let in the viewDidLoad method the text fields delegate as self? like in your example

Comment: yes i have like "self.UserNameTextField.delegate = self" same thing for the other two textfields

Comment: yes, is there any specific setting I have to check in the stimulator?

Comment: it will only be working on the keyboard appearing on the sim I think. If you are using your computer's keyboard I'm not sure if it will work. Please also see, I added also another way of dismissing the keyboard.

Comment: thanks! already using the keyboard on sim, will continue trying hopefully will work soon!

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class SignUpViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet var UsernameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var PasswordTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var EmailTextField: UITextField!

var ActivityIndicator:UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()
var currentTextField : UITextField?

func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.UsernameTextField.delegate = self
    self.PasswordTextField.delegate = self
    self.EmailTextField.delegate = self

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func BackToFirstPageButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    performSegueWithIdentifier("BackToLogInPage", sender: self)

}

func SignOutForEmailVerification() {

    PFUser.logOut()
    performSegueWithIdentifier("BackToLogInPage", sender: self)
}

@IBAction func SignUpButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    if UsernameTextField.text == "" || PasswordTextField.text == "" || EmailTextField.text == "" {

        let SignUpAlert = UIAlertController (title: "Error in form", message: "Please fill in the blanks", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        SignUpAlert.addAction((UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in

        })))

        self.presentViewController(SignUpAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    } else {

        currentTextField?.resignFirstResponder();

        ActivityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50))
        ActivityIndicator.center = self.view.center
        ActivityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        ActivityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
        view.addSubview(ActivityIndicator)
        ActivityIndicator.startAnimating()
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()

        var user = PFUser()
        user.username = UsernameTextField.text
        user.password = PasswordTextField.text
        user.email = EmailTextField.text

        user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success, error) -> Void in

            self.ActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()

            if error == nil {

                let EmailVerificationAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Email Verification", message: "Please click the link in an email we have just sent you", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

                EmailVerificationAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: .Default, handler: { EmailVerificationAlert in self.SignOutForEmailVerification()})
                )

                self.presentViewController(EmailVerificationAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }

        })
    }

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField!){

        currentTextField = textField;

    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {

        currentTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true

    }

}

}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. still no chance of dismissing... any other possible solutions? or is there any changes that I have to make in the stimulator?

Comment: textFieldShouldReturn is getting called or not?

Comment: no pressing the return button is not dismissing keyboard :(((